# Mixamo import edit clothing textures

Tags: texturing, armature

Thank you in advance for any help.
My question is regarding editing the colour of an mixamo armatures clothes.
I looked up some related questions and could not find anything that helped me.
I don't think this should be difficult but I have spent countless hours just trying to change the colour of the clothing of an import from mixamo. 
I can't find anything that explains how to do this.
I am relatively new to blender and I'm looking to import a mixamo character that has a suit on and I'd like to change colours of clothing items.  I played around with materials and nodes but could not figure it out.  I'm hoping there is a simple way to change colours.  I was able to apply some colour changes with texture painting but none of those changes were permanent.  They did not show up if I went to render or animation render.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figure out a solution for now.  I was able to use texture paint and switch to vertex mode to paint each part of the armature (shirt, body, tie, etc..)
These changes were permanent.   FYI it is not as good as textures but I am still trying to figure out how to change the colour of the original textures.  If I figure it out I will update.